# No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath' in kivy

Tags: python, numpy, kivy

I keep getting the below error when trying to import numpy in kivy on an android device.

`No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'`

Why am I getting this error if I already installed numpy where the main.py file is located and I also
made sure the file it is trying to import (_multiarray_umath) is located in the numpy library before building with buildozer, that is ->
**_multiarray_umath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so** located in **numpy/core**?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the entire error output?

Comment: Does your `buildozer.spec` file list `numpy` and `kivy` as `requirements`?

Comment: this can result from a failed (or interrupted) build. reinstalling numpy should do it.

Comment: Listing **numpy** in the **buildozer.spec** file fixed the error, but I can't seem to get tensorflow to compile in kivy for android. Does tensorflow not work in kivy on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you talk about is a desktop linux binary, not compatible with your android device. That is why it didn't work on android and (per the comments) the fix was to put numpy in the requirements so that an android version was built and included by buildozer.

> Listing numpy in the buildozer.spec file fixed the error, but I can't seem to get tensorflow to compile in kivy for android. Does tensorflow not work in kivy on android?

Tensorflow is not currently supported. Apparently tensorflow lite works, but you need to include it via gradle and write some java wrapper code to access it.